# Split data with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have data like this

```
[{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"},{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}]
```

I want split data to get:

1. `{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"}`
2. `{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}`

I am quite weak in regex please help.

Comment: Is parsing it with JSON not an option for you?

Comment: Is that string or array?

Comment: Neither the data you have nor the data you want to get are valid Ruby objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
collection = JSON.parse('[{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"},{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}]')
first = collection[0]
last = collection[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks this work for me.I forget that it json string and trying different way.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"},{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}]

arr[0] #{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"}
arr[1] #{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a single string in that format, it's likely you have a [JSON](http://www.json.org/) representation of a data structure.  You should use a json library to parse it into an array of hashes:

```
require 'json'
require 'pp'

s = '[{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"xyz"},{"search":true,"hidden":true,"index":"pqr","address":{"city":"xxxx"}}]'

a = JSON[s]
pp a

# => [{"search"=>true, "hidden"=>true, "index"=>"xyz"},
# =>  {"search"=>true, "hidden"=>true, "index"=>"pqr", "address"=>{"city"=>"xxxx"}}
```